# Elements aren't floating correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code a simple website, but I am stuck at the header part at the moment. For no reason, my elements doesn't flow as expected. The div "header_h" has to float to the left and the nav has to float to the right. But whenever I float one of the elements, its going out of the header. (Example: http://www.youscreen.de/yuphdkhlj00.jpg). When I float both at the same time like in the code, it looks like this: http://www.youscreen.de/isiqgladz04.jpg

This is how it has to look like: http://www.youscreen.de/sdbzjigvs77.jpg (created via height in the header, but thats not the solution I guess).

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#kopfbereich{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

header{
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#header_h{
  float: left;
}

nav{
  float: right;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Design #1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="kopfbereich">
      <header>
        <div id="header_h">
          <h1>Fancy</h1>
          <h2>Testsite</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks like a [clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known float problem.Apply clearfix to header it should work

Check this snippet

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#kopfbereich{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

header{
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.clearfix::after{
  display:table;
  visibility:hidden;
  clear:both;
  content:"";
}
#header_h{
  float: left;
}

nav{
  float: right;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div id="kopfbereich">
      <header class="clearfix">
        <div id="header_h">
          <h1>Fancy</h1>
          <h2>Testsite</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
```

Here [codepen](http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/dpLVNX)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that is the right answer to this question but only a working solution!
i guess your problem is just because you have set to `width:100%;` and `header` to `width:1000px;` so whatever the window(`body` tag) `width` is `kopfbereich` will have it too! but regardless to the window `width` the `header` is always `1000px` your problem only appears to be with the times that window has a `width` less than `1000px` and only colors that limited area but the menu links (`nav`) are floated at the right end of the `1000px` `header` .. but everything looks fine on a window with `width` more than `1000px`.

so for this very example i think you should take the `background-color` from `kopfbereich` and give it to `header` and u need to set `header`'s `height` to something too.. like

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#kopfbereich{
  width: 100%;

}

header{
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#header_h{
  float: left;
}

nav{
  float: right;
}

nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Design #1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="kopfbereich">
      <header>
        <div id="header_h">
          <h1>Fancy</h1>
          <h2>Testsite</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```